# Take the median of duplicated rownames

Tags: r

The `normal.meth` matrix may have duplicate rownames. If the rownames are duplicated, take the median and retain only one row each. For all the rows with unique rownames, keep it as-is. The output should not have duplicate rownames.

```
library(matrixStats)
normal.meth <- sapply(split.default(normal.meth, colnames(normal.meth)), rowMedians)
```

Input

```
> dput(normal.meth[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0.032865303709292, 0.52090224831803, 0.938794144634782, 
0.0245464559203754, 0.0219459912613677, 0.0379074157666324, 0.517612501352023, 
0.876290186551959, 0.0327330251402918, 0.0128121186436643, 0.0226085394857827, 
0.44294311681768, 0.747965490184437, 0.0181395446476151, 0.0125454991770939, 
0.0254179654232608, 0.55890575859087, 0.947559241210409, 0.0193177558971086, 
0.0105052884119836, 0.0276096307433916, 0.477774759564032, 0.817474068951357, 
0.0278807865780101, 0.0138086173417844), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("5S_rRNA", "5S_rRNA", "5S_rRNA", "ABC", "DEF"), 
    c("TCGA.A4.7288.11", "TCGA.BQ.5880.11", "TCGA.BQ.5879.11", 
    "TCGA.BQ.5883.11", "TCGA.BQ.7055.11")))
```

Desired output:

```
> dput(normal.meth[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0.0328653,  
0.0245464559203754, 0.0219459912613677, 0.03790742, 
0.0327330251402918, 0.0128121186436643, 0.02260854, 
0.0181395446476151, 0.0125454991770939, 
0.02541797, 0.0193177558971086, 
0.0105052884119836, 0.02760963, 
0.0278807865780101, 0.0138086173417844), dim = c(3L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("5S_rRNA", "ABC", "DEF"), 
    c("TCGA.A4.7288.11", "TCGA.BQ.5880.11", "TCGA.BQ.5879.11", 
    "TCGA.BQ.5883.11", "TCGA.BQ.7055.11")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: 
Here's a way which uses `*apply()` functions:

```
vapply(X = unique(rownames(normal.meth)), FUN = \(x) apply(normal.meth[rownames(normal.meth) == x ,, drop = FALSE], 2, median), FUN.VALUE = numeric(ncol(normal.meth)))
```

Original:
Here's a roundabout way, using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)

normal.meth |> 
  as.tibble(rownames = "r")|>
  summarise(across(everything(), median), .by = r) |>
  column_to_rownames("r") |>
  as.matrix()
```

Output:

```
        TCGA.A4.7288.11 TCGA.BQ.5880.11 TCGA.BQ.5879.11 TCGA.BQ.5883.11
5S_rRNA      0.52090225      0.51761250      0.44294312      0.55890576
ABC          0.02454646      0.03273303      0.01813954      0.01931776
DEF          0.02194599      0.01281212      0.01254550      0.01050529
        TCGA.BQ.7055.11
5S_rRNA      0.47777476
ABC          0.02788079
DEF          0.01380862
```